# Docker Error bind: address already in use when port is not in use

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, port, netstat

I'm running `docker-compose up` for the following docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  mysql_db_container:
    image: mysql:latest
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: rootpassword
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - mysql_db_data_container:/var/lib/mysql
  adminer_container:
    image: adminer:latest
    environment:
      ADMINER_DEFAULT_SERVER: mysql_db_container
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"

volumes:
  mysql_db_data_container:
```

and I'm getting the following error:

```
ERROR: for mysql_db_container  Cannot start service mysql_db_container: Ports are not available: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:3306: bind: address already in use
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

I've tried the follow:

```
docker-compose stop && docker-compose down
```

then

```
docker ps -a
```

results in:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
```

I ran:

```
netstat | grep :3306
```

it returned nothing.

I'm thinking the issue may be with the docker-compose file, but I'm not sure. Any ideas on how to free the port so the container can run are much appreciated.

Comment: check if on the computer is already running mysql or mariadb.

Comment: Try the below commands,
docker-compose down - This will stop the containers on the current directory if there is a docker-compose.yml

docker rm -fv $(docker ps -aq) - All the containers will be removed

sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep 3306- List who's using the port

kill -9 3306

Also try restarting docker to see if it resolves the issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The cause:
MySQL was already running on the computer.

The solution:
On mac:
System Preferences > MySQL > Stop MySQL Server

Comment: run > services > Mysql > stop this works even on windows!